# Jumping from a custom callout to another one in MKMap

Tags: iphone, xcode, annotations, mapkit, mkannotation

I've been following this [tutorial](http://blog.asolutions.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-1/) to show custom annotation callout bubbles.
It works perfectly if you have only one annotation with a custom annotationview.

However, I need to have more on my map, and I have troubles switching from a custom annotationview to another one. If I  click on another pin when having selected already one and would like to make appear the new custom annotationview, it doesn't work. I have first to click somewhere else random on the mapview. I guess I have something to work on in DidDeselect Method, but I'm not sure...

How would you solve such a problem?

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
    if (self.calloutAnnotation && [view.annotation isKindOfClass:[MyHomeAnnotation class]]) {
        [self.mapView removeAnnotation: self.calloutAnnotation];
    }
}
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
     if ([view.annotation isKindOfClass:[MyHomeAnnotation class]]) { 
        if (self.calloutAnnotation == nil) {
            self.calloutAnnotation = [[CalloutMapAnnotation alloc] initWithLatitude:view.annotation.coordinate.latitude
                                                                       andLongitude:view.annotation.coordinate.longitude];
        } else {
            self.calloutAnnotation.latitude = view.annotation.coordinate.latitude;
            self.calloutAnnotation.longitude = view.annotation.coordinate.longitude;
        }
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:self.calloutAnnotation];
        self.selectedAnnotationView = view;
    }
}



- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    if (annotation == self.calloutAnnotation) {
        CalloutMapAnnotationView *calloutMapAnnotationView = (CalloutMapAnnotationView *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"CalloutAnnotation"];
        if (!calloutMapAnnotationView) {
            calloutMapAnnotationView = [[[CalloutMapAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation 
                                                                             reuseIdentifier:@"CalloutAnnotation"] autorelease];
            calloutMapAnnotationView.contentHeight = 78.0f;
            UIImage *asynchronyLogo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cykelrød1.png"];
            UIImageView *asynchronyLogoView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:asynchronyLogo] autorelease];
            asynchronyLogoView.frame = CGRectMake(5, 2, asynchronyLogoView.frame.size.width, asynchronyLogoView.frame.size.height);
            [calloutMapAnnotationView.contentView addSubview:asynchronyLogoView];
        }
        calloutMapAnnotationView.parentAnnotationView = self.selectedAnnotationView;
        calloutMapAnnotationView.mapView = self.mapView;
        return calloutMapAnnotationView;
    } else if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MyHomeAnnotation class]]) {
        MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation 
                                                                               reuseIdentifier:@"CustomAnnotation"] autorelease];
        annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;
        annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
        return annotationView;
    }else if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MyMapAnnotation class]]) {
        MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation 
                                                                               reuseIdentifier:@"NormalAnnotation"] autorelease];
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
        return annotationView;
    }


    return nil;
}
```

Comment: I don't really use the MKMap framework much, so I really cannot help you.... all I can say is can you make a subview of the `MKMapView` class, and simulate a tap elsewhere on the map view, and pass that to the superview? that makes it so it thinks there was a previous tap when there actually isn't....

Comment: it sounds like this is what I should do, however I have no idea on how to do that...

Answer (score 4):

Here are my solution, I use latitude and longitude to distinguish which callout should be remove from mapview. Hope this will be help.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
   NSLog(@"didSelectAnnotationView:%f", view.annotation.coordinate.latitude);

   if (self.calloutAnnotation == nil) {

      CalloutMapAnnotation *tempCallout = [[CalloutMapAnnotation alloc] 
                                         initWithLatitude:view.annotation.coordinate.latitude              
                                         andLongitude:view.annotation.coordinate.longitude];

      self.calloutAnnotation = tempCallout;
      [tempCallout release];

  } else {

      //remove callout when callout already exist
      [self.myMapView removeAnnotation: self.calloutAnnotation];
      self.selectedAnnotationView = nil;

      //reposition
      self.calloutAnnotation.latitude = view.annotation.coordinate.latitude;
      self.calloutAnnotation.longitude = view.annotation.coordinate.longitude;

  }

  [self.myMapView addAnnotation:self.calloutAnnotation];
  self.selectedAnnotationView = view;
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view   {

  NSLog(@"didDeselectAnnotationView:%f", view.annotation.coordinate.latitude);

  //use the latitude and longitude to avoid remove twice

  if (self.calloutAnnotation &&
    self.selectedAnnotationView.annotation.coordinate.latitude == view.annotation.coordinate.latitude &&
    self.selectedAnnotationView.annotation.coordinate.longitude == view.annotation.coordinate.longitude
    ) {

      [self.myMapView removeAnnotation: self.calloutAnnotation];
      self.selectedAnnotationView = nil;
      self.calloutAnnotation.isAddtoMap = NO;
  }

}
```